# Remove HTML that was added by AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page where I build orders. The page fully works with ajax to find products and add them to the page.

Now, if you add an item and need to remove it, I was building functionality to do so:

```
$('.orderRemove').click(function() {
    var removeID = $(this).attr("id");
    $("#item-" + removeID).remove();
    calculateTotal();
});
```

But since .orderRemove is added by AJAX it doesn't work.

How do I go about making this exact call work, removing the full block that was added by ajax.

Thank you

Comment: Try `$('.orderRemove').on("click",function()` instead

Comment: That didn't work either.

Comment: Then try `$("body").on("click", ".orderRemove", function(){`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is dynamically added HTML to the DOM does not attach itself to the event handlers so either re-attach the event handler in the ajax success call back or try [`.delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) if you are using jQuery version less than `1.7` or [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) if you are using jQuery version 1.7 or higher

```
$(document).delegate('.orderRemove','click',function() {
    var removeID = $(this).attr("id");
    $("#item-" + removeID).remove();
    calculateTotal();
});
```

example with .on

```
$(document).on('click','.orderRemove',function() {
   var removeID = $(this).attr("id");
   $("#item-" + removeID).remove();
  calculateTotal();
});
```

Comment: It would be much more efficient to bind to a more-specific element than the entire document, as that binding will process _all_ clicks anywhere; generally, OP wants to bind to the actual element whose contents are being populated through AJAX.

Comment: @mplungjan sry i didnt know that .on has also been deprecated... so its delegate they are using now a days? i have come back to jQuery after a bit of time so ...

Comment: `.on()` is not deprecated, `.delegate()` is deprecated in favor of `.on()`.

Comment: @lanzz oh... ok i have given both the examples, coz .on is not available up till version 1.7

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `on` like this

```
$(document).on('click','.orderRemove',function() {
   var removeID = $(this).attr("id");
   $("#item-" + removeID).remove();
  calculateTotal();
});
```